# The combined usage of min and max() in a graph definition.

Tags: graph-theory

Mpq(z) is defined as

$$M_{pq} (z)  = \large \min_{x,y\in N(z)\setminus \{p,q\}} \max \left(\begin{array}{c}l(xz)+l(zp)-l(xp), \\ l(yz)+l(zp)-l(yp), \\ l(xz)+l(zq)-l(xq), \\ l(yz)+l(zq)-l(yq) \end{array} \right)$$

The first equation in max() is

```
l(xz) + l(zp) – l(xp),
```

Where l(xp) is the Euclidean length of edge xp rounded to the nearest integer.
This is very similar to the triangle inequality equation.
Vertex ‘z’ is some point on edge pq (see diagram below).

```
        x *
                                 * y

  *-----------------*----------------------*
  p                 z                      q
```

The question is, why is min used in the above definition, and how does it affect max()?

Note:
This definition is located in the paper, Edge Elimination in TSP Instances, by Stefan Hougardy and Rasmus T. Schroeder (at https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7301), in section 4 on page 5.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $p$, $q$, and $z$.  For each $x,y$, compute the $\max$ of the four expressions.  Now take the smallest of these maximum values.

It is a similar idea to the definition of the *diameter* of a graph, which is:
$$\max_{i,j\in N} \min_{\text{paths $P$ from $i$ to $j$}} \{\text{length of $P$}\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll attempt to use this information to figure out how the Strong Close Point Elimination Theorem (metric excess) is implemented in the paper, Edge Elimination in TSP Instances.